# CSS transitions with the "checked" hack

Tags: css, css-transitions

I'm trying to do something similar with this example by using the "checked" hack

```
input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ label .box { 
  opacity:0;
  -webkit-transform   :scale(0) rotate(-180deg);
  -moz-transform      :scale(0) rotate(-180deg);
  transform           :scale(0) rotate(-180deg);
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KVWWjy

However, I need to change the html code so that the label tag is before the input tag. When I move the input in the bottom the effects stop working. how can I fix this?

Comment: I don't even know what the previous sibling is but ok...

Comment: Well, shame they closed it. I had your answer

Comment: @LOTUSMS can you pm it to me?

Comment: No idea we could PM here lol. PM me and I'll reply ...I guess you learn something new every day

Comment: My bad. I guess it can't be done

Comment: Wait, I'm building a codepen for ya

Comment: With a little CSS beautification in a separate question, you can get the animations. But at least your input after label conundrum will be solved

Comment: Here. If you need help with the CSS animations, open up a new question and make sure it doesn't sound anything like other ones or even this one. Because , even though is a different problem, they'll flag it  - http://codepen.io/anon/pen/obZWPx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no `previous sibling` selector in CSS. If it there was, CSS would be a lot slower. There has been a lot of debate on this subject and it won't happen in any foreseeable future.

As [chowey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2105930/chowey) very well put it:

> CSS selectors are designed to be easy (fast) to implement for the browser. The document can be traversed once, matching elements as you go, with no need to ever go backward to adjust a match

Simply put, you'll have to change your markup. You can't make CSS look backwards. It only looks forward.

For more info on the subject, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817792/is-there-a-previous-sibling-css-selector).

Answer (score 0):

With `css` this is impossible as you cannot traverse up, the selector you use only looks at the next siblings it dosent work backwards. For this to work you'd have to use `Javascript`.